# Service account API Key usage for Google Cloud Storage JSON API

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-storage, google-api-nodejs-client

I want to use Google Cloud Storage JSON API to upload some JSON as file into Cloud Storage. My code is as follows:

```
import google from 'googleapis';
import fs from 'fs';

export function uploadFileToStorage(json, callback) {
  const storage = google.storage({
    version: 'v1'
  });
  // 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'

  const request = {
     bucket: 'bucket-id',
     resource: {},
     uploadType: 'media',
     name: 'test',
     media: {
       mimeType: 'application/json',
       body: json
     },
     auth: 'api-key'
   };

   storage.objects.insert(request, callback);
}
```

The JSON is passed on to the uploadFileToStorage() function. The function is using googleapis to connect to Google Cloud Storage. The code should work, but I am not able to pass the api key correctly.

[image]

It is throwing a 400 - Bad request error.

[image]